# Preventing overscroll in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I have a site has a `<div>` on it that is vertically scrollable.  That works well.  I am also hiding the scrollbar, and that also works well.  CSS is essentially

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

I am currently having a problem, though, with it in Internet Explorer 11 and Windows 7 on a touch enabled display.  When a user hits the top of bottom of the scroll, the window bounces (ie, there is overscroll).  While this would just be an annoyance for most users, this is running fullscreen in a kiosk, so the overscoll allows the desktop to peek through (not just the browser background).

I have been unsuccessful at figuring out a solution to this.  [`touch-action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767313.aspx) (prefixed and not), eg

```
html, body, .scrollable {
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

doesn't seem to do anything, nor do

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('MSPointerMove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

[This jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vabijaya/1) shows the problem.

So, what is the proper way to prevent overscroll in IE11 / Windows 7.

Comment: Recently [overscroll-behavior](https://caniuse.com/#search=overscroll-behavior) was added to Firefox 59 and Chrome 65 and will be added to Edge 18.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box (see what I did there) would giving the parent element - `body`, `section` or even another `div` a background colour mitigate the main issue of the desktop showing through?

Otherwise have a look at the

```
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
```

property from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772034(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which looks like it might fix your problem - though I have no way to test it myself.

Comment: Keep us posted if this does fix it, as I have not come across that problem before - note to self, save up to buy touch screen win7 box ;)

Comment: fyi link found by searching google for 'scroll bounce on ie11 touch'

Comment: This doesn't prevent the overscrolls / bounce.  The MSDN link provided also mentions that this only works in Windows 8 and above.

Comment: "This is an IE specific workaround and disables scroll chaining (--ms-scroll-chaining: none) on root scroller. This actually does not work well in practice as it only prevents overscroll action if the page is not scrolled fully to its extent and requires the page to be scrollable" - from https://discourse.wicg.io/t/proposal-api-to-control-user-gesture-navigation/1536

Answer (score 1):

The overscroll bounce effect is not limited to Internet Explorer 11 and can be seen in even simple applications, such as Notepad.

To disable the effect, set the following registry key to "0":

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch\Bouncing
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry should have tested before posting answer.

I tested the jsbin problem and solved it like this. Assign these styles to the `scrollie` class:

```
.scrollie {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.  The whole window still moves when you try to scroll at the extreme.  Also, you can just edit your original answer.  No need to post new ones.

Comment: It did solve it in the JS Bin but, yeah i was not 100 % sure that it would work in iE

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be solved with the word-wrap property in css3.I also addded a overflow-x:hidden just to be sure.

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow-x:hidden;
            }
```

Here you can read more about word-wrap here-
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

If you didnt understand any part of my question, or this didnt solve your problem, please comment and tell me so as i am open to answering more questions.

Comment: This doesn't fix it in the JSBin example I posted, nor in the actual site.

Comment: @MPD see my new answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

or

```
.scrollable {
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: The window still overscrolls / bounces with this.

Answer (score -2):

I believe I fixed it by adding the following to your CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can see the results at [this updated jsBin](http://jsbin.com/vabijaya/4)

Comment: The window still overscrolls / bounces with this.